# Can you explain what the 'index of ___' sites are?

Tags: google-search, www

I recently discovered that if you search on Google 'index of **_' (where _** is a name of a TV serie, for instance the mythical Lost) you find a list of episodes that are available for download.

These sites are rather strange, I didn't find anything on the web about them.

Do someone know how do they work and if it is safe to download from them?

Comment: They are FTP sites and you are just connecting to the websites directory structure or file server. Sometimes safe, sometimes not. Use best judgement. For more info, search how to host an ftp server

Comment: Those are most likely just public FTP sites. Doesn't mean they're safe or not, but they are not part of some "Index of" collection. "Index of" is found on every server (e.g. ftp://speedtest.tele2.net/) and just means, here's the list of files/folders in this directory.